# Как перевести тип std::chrono::system_clock::time_point в string?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

Как перевести тип  `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point` в `std::string`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот три разных варианта, выбирайте

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{

    auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto tt = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now);
    
    {
        // просто вывод в консоль
        std::cout << std::put_time(std::localtime(&tt), "%F %T") << '\n';
    }
    {
        // выводим в строковый поток, потом уже в строку
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << std::put_time(std::localtime(&tt), "%F %T");
        std::string st = ss.str();
        std::cout << st << '\n';
    }
    {
        // в массив символов, потом выводим, но для программистов на си это уже строка
        char buf[100];
        strftime(buf, 100, "%F %T", std::localtime(&tt));
        std::cout << buf;
    }
}
```

Comment: судя по всему, это не тот тип.

Comment: судя по документации, именно Вашего типа нет. Или он просто синоним этого. Показывайте код, который возвращает переменную этого типа, я подкорректирую код

Comment: Я использую библиотеку ozo для работы с пг, в качестве нативного типа для работы с timestemp она использует именно этот тип из стандартной библиотеки. Данный тип является следующим алиасом   typedef chrono::time_point<system_clock, duration>  time_point;

Comment: попробуйте мой код. Он должен отработать.

Comment: Я попробовал, не работает с этим тмаом

Comment: а, нет, все хорошо, оказывается now возвращает как раз этот тип, спасибо

Comment: Однако стоит иметь ввиду, что `std::localtime` может быть небезопасна при использовании в многопоточной среде.